# angular tree need array reverse traverse and check parent json element

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs, json

I am creating angular tree which will select child as well as parent element by clicking on any level of li element(I have provided checkbox for all). see the fiddle http://plnkr.co/edit/IJhKdkzyZFmLEIUzanNB?p=preview

currently the child elements are selected properly at any stage(done with angular loop and condition) but the parent elements are not consistently selected(working fine at only at start) because it has been selected through by jquery. and parent values are also not present in final output (click event on below link) which i have get in console output.
Need array reverse traverse to trace parent element which will do both the work, selection on check box and push element name in console output.

```
   scope.checkNode = function (node) {
                node.checked = !node.checked;

                function checkChildren(c) {
                    angular.forEach(c.subOrgEntityDTOList, function (c) {
                        c.checked = node.checked;
                        checkChildren(c);
                    });

                }

                checkChildren(node);

            };
```

Comment: If you're implementing doubly linked lists use the `previous` method on each node